# Establishing SSE connection over https fails - How to resolve that

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

As far as I have understood, to establish an event stream one must create an event source object on the client passing it an endpoint to the server to register itself with. The server upon receiving this request, sets the response headers appropriately and sends data following the event stream format. I have this flow set up and it works over http but after adding SSL to the server, the event stream is getting created and the server throws a 501 - Not implemented error. After some research, I assumed it might be a CORS issue and added the appropriate headers but that didn't make a difference either. I have also tried small fixes that usually work for 501 errors like clearing browser cache and disabling any proxy settings. I'm completely puzzled by this and would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand the problem and best way to fix it.

EDIT:

The client sends a request to the server through aws elb load balancer that strips off ssl from requests and forwards requests to the server. The other possible reason for the server to throw a 501 error apart from CORS related issues is that the request was altered.

Is it possible that when the load balancer removes SSL from the requests before forwarding it to the server, it alters sse requests in some way causing the server to throw the error? How would one monitor the requests coming in to the load balancer and the requests being forwarded?
Also, upon further research I have understood that internally Server Side Events are essentially a form of HTTP Streaming. The request is kept open even after data is sent until it is explicitly closed by the client. Considering that my first hunch is wrong, the SSL is stripped off and forwarded to the server without altering the request and the server sends the response headers and also heartbeat signals to keep the connection alive.

Does that mean the stream is also encrypted?
The server is written in Koa. Here's what the sse registration endpoint looks like:

Comment: you should set headers    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

Answer (score -1):

```
// node.js

const SseStream = require('ssestream');

console.log('SseStream', SseStream)

const MyService = {
   doSomeStuff: () => {return 222}
}


public async someFunctionInRouter(req,res) {
    const origin = req.get('origin') || '';
    const sseStream = new SseStream(req);

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log("res.on('end'");
    });
    res.on('close', () => {
      console.log("res.on('close'");
      sseStream.unpipe(res);
    });
    res.on('error', ee => {
      console.log("res.on('error'", ee);
      sseStream.write({
        id: 3,
        event: 'myCustomEvent',
        data: {
          errors: [ee]
        }
      });
    });
    sseStream.pipe(res);



    const result = await MyService.doSomeStuff(999, 888)
      .catch(e => {
        console.error('error', e);
        sseStream.write({
          id: 2,
          event: 'myCustomEvent',
          data: {
            errors: [e]
          }
        });
      });

    sseStream.on('end', (eeee: any) => {
      console.log('sseStream.on error', eeee);
    });
    sseStream.on('error', (eeee: any) => {
      console.log('sseStream.on error', eeee);
    });
    sseStream.on('close', (eeee: any) => {
      console.log('sseStream.on close', eeee);
    });

    sseStream.write({
      id: 1,
      event: 'myCustomEvent',
      data: result
    });

    res.end();
  }
```

Comment: What is this?  An answer that is purely a large block of code with no explanation (and no descriptive comments in the code) will leave many confused and will always be a better answer if you add some explanation for what you're telling the OP their problem is.